# Image of a closed unit ball of non-reflexive space

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $A:c_0\to L_2[0,1]$, $Ax(t)=\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{x(k)}{ k!+ t}$ -- is linear operator. It is required to prove or disprove the closedness of the set $A(B_1(0))$, where $B_1(0)$ -- closed unit ball in $c_0$.

What I already know about this operator: it's well defined, bounded, compact. I can find his adjoint. If instead of $c_0$ there was a reflexive space, I could say that the set $A(B_1(0))$ is closed (even compact). Is it possible to use the above information for this case, or should I act somehow differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Consider the function
$$
f(t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!+t},
\qquad
t\in[0,1].
$$
To show this is not in $A(B_1(0))$, one can use monotonicity arguments.
For example, it turns out that $(Ax)(t)\leq f(t)$ for all $t\in[0,1]$
and $x\in B_1(0)$ holds. Similar ideas can be used to show that $f\not\in A(B_1(0))$.

Comment: I thought about it, but how to show that she does not have a preimage? I mean, what if exists $x\in c_0$ such that $\sum\frac{x(k)}{k!+t}=\sum\frac{1}{k!+t}$?

Comment: @thing I edited my answer to provide a hint for the questions in your comment.

Comment: If $\forall x\in B_1(0)$ $\sum\frac{x(k)}{k!+t}\leq\sum\frac{1}{k!+t}=\sum\frac{x_0(k)}{k!+t}$ for some $x_0\in B_1(0)$, then what does it give? I don't see how to get a contradiction.

Comment: I think i understand. If $\sum\frac{1-x_0(k)}{k!+t}=0$, then, by nonnegativity of $1-x_0(k)$, $x_0(k)=1$.

Comment: Sorry, could you please tell me one more thing: if instead of $c_0$ there was a $c$, I would like to consider $x_0(k)=(-1)^k$. But the same reasoning does not work out for him. Maybe there are other reasoning, or even a completely different example?

Comment: @thing this seems to be more complicated. I am not sure but I would still guess that the image of the closed unit ball is not closed.